# How to retrieve list of projects within an organisation by running a query in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I want all the projects within a collection (organization) listed by running a query.

I searched so many resources but I hadn't got any relevant results. anybody

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do ith with query.

You can do it with Rest API [Projects - List,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for example in PowerShell:

```
$pat = "YOUR-PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,"$pat")))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$azureDevOpsUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{your-organization-name}"

$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$azureDevOpsUrl/_apis/projects" -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that list if you visit Organization Page. And you cannot get that list using queries, you should REST APIs.

There is an extension in Azure DevOps Marketplace which lists projects and properties like process template etc. you can take a look at it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.VSTS-TeamProject-Monitor)

Answer (score 0):

To get more information on how to create a PAT token review [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)

```
# Azure DevOps PAT Token
$AzureDevOpsPAT = ""

# Azure DevOps Org Name
$OrganizationName = ""

# Header sting used for Authentication to Azure DevOps
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

# Base URI for the query
$UriOrga = "https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/" 

# Base URI + Resource with the REST API
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "_apis/projects?api-version=5.1"

# Invoke the query 
$Projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 

# Show the project Names only
$Projects.value
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**